# Where can i find 32 bit java for OSx

Tags: java, macos, titanium, 32-bit

I am trying to use titanium studio for mobile app development. The titanium studio IDE requires your system to have 32 bit java and will not work for 64 bit. I cant seem to find 32 bit for my mac operating system. I dont need java 8 either, I need java 6 or 7 and preferably 7.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should go to http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Prerequisites.

Secondly, what is the version of your **Titanium Studio**?
Latest version requires **64-bit Java** and minimum **OS X Mavericks**.

> **OS X Notes:**
>
> Starting with Titanium SDK 3.4.0, iOS development requires Mavericks due to Xcode 6 requirements.
>
> If you are using Studio 3.1.x, it supports Mac OS X 10.7.x (Lion) or 10.8.x (Mountain Lion) but not Mavericks.

[image]

Comment: thank you. i was using windows before so i was use to the 32 bit java and my professor for mobile programming told me I need 32 bit of java and I just took his word for it. Thanks for the link. It really cleared up alot for me

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember there is no 32bit support for java 7 on MacOS

https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_install.xml